# Open cv camera calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am running the camera calibration program present in the opencv\sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\calib3d\camera_calibration folder . 
  When i try to run the source code in release mode i get the , i get a buffer overrun error saying

> A buffer overrun has occurred in Camera calibration_19.10.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program.

where Camera calibration_19.10 is the name of the project i am compiling my source code in.

The question here is that what is the mistake in the code or the linked libraries resulting in the above error to pop up ??.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: do you link the debug libraries in release mode?

Comment: @Micka , Yes i had linked myvisual studio 2012 to C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib . The error was it needed to be linked to C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib as visual studio 2012  uses vc11. When i copied the dll for vc11 to my debug and release folder the executable for my project worked fine . :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my project was i had set my opencv libraries to \opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib . But visual studio needed \opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib.
   So when i used the .dlls(opencv_world300.dll,opencv_world300d.dll) from \opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin into my project debug and release folder , the executables worked fine without the above mentioned error

P.S if u get the above error when using visual studio 2012. use \opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin dll's instead of \opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin dll's and all ist gut. :D